# ActionBarDrawerToggle issue on Android

Tags: android

well guys, I'm development a private personal app for my job, but I'm having an unknown issue, I'm kind of lost with this, not understanding what is this happening, I'm trying to setup a simple ActionBarDrawerToggle, but it doesn't working, and It's even showing and unset Icon instead I setted, so please, can anybody help me? I couldn't go ahead if I don't resolve this first

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] titulos;
    private DrawerLayout NavDrawerLayout;
    private ListView NavList;
    private ArrayList<Item_objct> NavItms;
    private TypedArray NavIcons;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    NavigationAdapter NavAdapter;

//Implementacion del ListView
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Drawer Layout
    NavDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //Lista
    NavList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    //Declaramos el header el caul sera el layout de header.xml
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    //Establecemos header
    NavList.addHeaderView(header);
    //Tomamos listado  de imgs desde drawable
    NavIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.navigation_iconos);
    //Tomamos listado  de titulos desde el string-array de los recursos @string/nav_options
    titulos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_options);
    //Listado de titulos de barra de navegacion
    NavItms = new ArrayList<Item_objct>();
    //Agregamos objetos Item_objct al array
    //Pedidos
    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[0], NavIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    //Gastos
    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[1], NavIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    //Productos
    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[2], NavIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    //Clientes
    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[3], NavIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    //Ganancias
    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[4], NavIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    //Capital
    NavItms.add(new Item_objct(titulos[5], NavIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    //Declaramos y seteamos nuestrp adaptador al cual le pasamos el array con los titulos
    NavAdapter= new NavigationAdapter(this,NavItms);
    NavList.setAdapter(NavAdapter);
    //Siempre vamos a mostrar el mismo titulo
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // Declaramos el mDrawerToggle y las imgs a utilizar
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                   /*Host Activity*/
            NavDrawerLayout,        /*DrawerLayout Object*/
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,   /*Icono de navegacion*/
            R.string.app_name,      /* Nombre de aplicacion*/
            R.string.hello_world    /* "Close drawer" description*/
    ) {
        /**
         * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state
         */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            Log.e("Cerrado Completo", "!!");
        }

        /**
         * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state
         */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Log.e("Apertura Completa", "!!");
        }
    };

    //Establecemos que mDrawerToggle declarado anteriormente sea el DrawerListener
    NavDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    //Establecemos que el ActionBar muestre el boton Home
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

That is my Main Activity class, I just don't find the asnwer why this

Comment: You can get Android Studio to create a fully working nav bar activity for you via New -> Activity.

Comment: Yes you're right, but I'm not ready to use that way yet, I'm beginner , and those auto created classes have a lot of methods than I have no idea what they're for, so for now, I prefer to develop by myself method instead use those templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to add some things:

1.-Override following Activity methods to sync DrawerToggle with the state:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

2.- Also, you need to tell the ActionBar than home icon must be enabled. So call the following in OnCreate for example:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I hope this helps you.

If this does not help you, check:http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html Its a good guide

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much BamsBamx definitely the issue was on those undeclared methods, I declared them and It just work. Thank you so much

Comment: @MaToXz please, could you accept the answer (click on the tick at the left side of the screen? I would thank you a lot

Comment: @BamsBamx I've override `onPostCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` methods, but after activity is created my hamburger icon is not working. After I slide a drawer by swiping from left, hamburger icon starts to work as expected. Any idea?

Comment: @IvanBajalovic did you call Toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()?

Comment: @BamsBamx I tried also with `mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener` but this event is not triggered.

Comment: @IvanBajalovic then I think you should post a new question and show your code. It would be easier to found your probem